# Problems with drivers for ATI Radeon 4500 after upgraded to 14.04

Tags: drivers, ati, xorg, 14.04, radeon

I upgraded to 14.04 and have managed to break by graphics drivers. I'm not even sure where I'm at now.

I have a Dell Studio 15 with a ATI Radeon 4500 video card. I know this is no longer supported by the latest proprietary drivers, so if I'm not mistaken I can just use the default xserver drivers (xserver-xorg-video-radeon)??

After my system upgrade I was able to login, but only when using the Recovery option from my grub menu (and just selecting the first option to continue to start up). I only had low resolutions available to me (up to 1024 instead of 1366) and everything was very slow. So I tried installing different drivers, and even tried the ubuntu-amd-catalyst-install from http://www.thefanclub.co.za/how-to/ubuntu-amd-catalyst-install, but that made things worse and has destroyed X for me.

How can I recover from this, and get things running nicely again?

I've tried to reinstall xserver-xorg-video-radeon but it fails with a dependency problem (xorg-video-abi-15, which is part of xserver-xorg-core). I try to install xserver-xorg-core and it tells me "reinstallation of xserver-xorg-core is not possible, it cannot be downloaded"

Comment: Please, do not add [SOLVED] to the title and do not add solution into the body. Instead, answer your own question and accept it once it will be allowed.

Answer (score 2):

The problem [was solved](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/457498/2) by the OP (original poster). I'm posting it in order to keep site cleaner.

> Well, I think I have fixed my problem right after pasting:
>
> I did
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get remove --purge xserver-xorg-*
> ```
>
> followed by
>
> ```
> apt-get install xserver-org
> ```
>
> rebooted and was able to log in, even with full resolution.

Answer (score 0):

You need the 13.1 AMD driver, this link works for the 32bit system

http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop/legacy?product=Legacy2&os=Linux%20x86

Comment: Legacy hardware (pre HD5000) is not supported any more, see [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/471609/amd-ati-radeon-hd-4870-drivers-on-ubuntu-14-04/471638#471638)